# How to use sub-query result as an input to the other query in Solr?

Tags: solr, solr4

Say I have an index with the following fields:

Id, Surname, Country, Age

What would be Solr query syntax to achieve something that in SQL could be expressed as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE country = (SELECT country FROM table WHERE id = 123);
```

The catch - I would like this to be just one query rather that two separate ones.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change your data structure a bit.
It's not SQL and it don't have relations, so you will have to map manually.

***Document:***

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Surname": "myname",
    "CountryId": 1,
    "Age": 49
}
```

***Query:***

http://my.solr/solr/table/select:

```
{
    "q": "*:*",
    "fq": "CountryId: 49",
    "fl": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to denormalize your data, please try [Join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-JoinQueryParser) or [Block Join](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-BlockJoinQueryParsers).
One example of `Join` is:

```
{
    "q":"{!join fromIndex=country from=id to=country}*:*"
}
```

But it will be very slow when you have a large number of data, such as millions of entries for each core.